# How do I say something "contains a lot of content" using a single word?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do I say that something "contains a lot of content" with a single word?

Is there an English word for this statement?

- *something* — may be a text, an article, a blog post
- *contains a lot of content* — contains good, new information that is usable for users
- *a lot* — is only about quantity, not about "a wide variety of types" or anything like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [comprehensive](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/comprehensive?q=comprehensive) especially in a positive sense

> complete and including everything that is necessary

Comment: Hmm.  Something can easily contain a lot of content, and yet not be comprehensive.

Answer (score 10):

A number of words might be suitable, depending on the context. They include *copious, abundant, lavish, rich, extensive, ample, overflowing, bountiful* and *profuse*.

Answer (score 8):

The text, article or blog post is said to be *[informative](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/informative)*.

Comment: +1... *Informative* is a succinct way of saying that the writing contains useful or quality information. That said, however, the word doesn't convey to me any sense of volume or verbosity.

Comment: @bracho I agree. _Something_ may also contain a lot of useless or noisy _content_, which may not meet the asker's needs.

Comment: *informative* is a qualitative attribute, OP's question relates to *quantity*.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a word that is unambiguously positive, use ***[informative](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/informative)***. If you want to emphasize quantity a bit more, and don't mind a possibly-negative connotation, you can use ***[dense](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dense)*** or maybe ***[packed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/packed)***.

Comment: You could even say "information-dense" or "information-packed" to rule out the negative connotation. Even without it, I increasingly hear "dense" used in this way: *Wow, that article is really dense. I'm going to have to go over it again to really understand it all.*

Comment: Density is relative: a unit of quantity per unit volume. A small quantity can still be *dense* or *packed* if it occupies a relatively small amount of space. Density says nothing of the absolute quantity.

Comment: @Kris, in this case, the absolute quantity is a given. Whatever the something is — a book, an article, whatever — it has a certain length. What the OP wants (I think) is a way to say that within that length, there is a large amount of actual content, i.e. very little fluff or filler. This is precisely what "dense" means.

Answer (score 1):

You can say that something is [bloated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bloated), although it often expresses the concept with a somewhat negative connotation.

Comment: The connotations of "bloated" are *always* quite negative.

Comment: Except when it applies to one's bank account.

Comment: ...or if someone is said to be "positively bloated" :P

Answer (score 1):

I'd tend to use "wordy", although its use is somewhat negative, implying that there are more words than necessary.